# Docker application expose ALSA sound on TCP Ports

Tags: linux, docker, audio, loopback, alsa

Hi I am fairly new to Docker and have about zero knowledge about sound on Linux.

I want to run an application in a docker container that always uses the default ALSA sound card as both input and output. I want to create a virtual soundcard that (maybe with the help of some other tool like ffmpeg?) routes the sound to two exposed TCP Ports "A" and "B". One (A) for in- and one (B) for output of sound. Something like this:

```
write PCM -----> TCP Port A -----> <Alsa Magic> -----> Standard "Microphone" input
read  PCM <----- TCP Port B <----- <Alsa Magic> <----- Standard "Speaker" output
```

Additionally I would like that multiple host applications can connect and write to Port A so that their sound is automatically mixed together in the container and passed to the mic and that mutliple host applications can read the same audio from Port B.

Mono audio is all I need for both directions. If someone could help me out and maybe even show me how to do this with a Dockerfile I'd be really thankful :)

Comment: Docker containers don't have "virtual devices", and you need some complex setup to access host devices from a container.  [unix.se] might be a better place to ask about this.  Running outside a container directly on the host will definitely be easier.

Comment: Im not speaking about virtual devices like in full fledged VMs. Cant I create a Docker Container with the ALSA sound system and define a virtual ALSA loopback device for it? And then redirect the sound to a Port through some other means?